# Passing a project name to the angular material schematic?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cli

I created a new project workspace and then an application and library within the workspace.

```
ng new workspace --create-application=false
cd workspace
ng g library testlibrary
ng g application playground
```

Then I added Angular Material:

```
ng add @angular/material
The package @angular/material@15.2.3 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
? Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Custom
? Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes
? Include the Angular animations module? Include and enable animations
UPDATE package.json (1128 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
Project name is required.
```

It logged. project name is required at the end, making me think that it's possible to pass a project name to the schematic.

How do we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `--project <target project name>`